# What is the meaning of the subscript in the abbreviations of some minerals?

Tags: mineralogy, terminology

I have noticed that in many articles on minerals that I have read the abbreviation of some mineral has a numerical subscript, for example, occurs with the forsterite (Fo<sub>95-90</sub>, Fo<sub>92-84</sub>, Fo<sub>94</sub>, etc.). What is the meaning of this subscript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Olivine is a [solid solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_solution) between forsterite and fayalite, so it is generally expressed as molar percentages of these end-members, for instance Fo<sub>80</sub>Fa<sub>20</sub>. Often only one end-member is mentioned, as it is sufficient to infer the other (their sum is always 100 %).

It is the same with plagioclase, which is a solid solution between albite and anorthite and is often expressed as "Ab<sub>xx</sub>" or "An<sub>xx</sub>", where xx is the molar percentage of considered end-member.

Edit: As for the range, e.g. 95-90, I'd say they analyzed several olivine grains in the same sample, and the range represents the variability of compositions they found. It could also be the analytical error on a single composition, but I doubt it would be that large, although it could be in some old papers when the precision of chemical analyses was not as good as today.